# Weird looking glyphs while installing vim-devicons for neovim

Tags: neovim, vim-plugin, glyphicons, vim-airline

I was setting up `neovim`, and was installing `air-line` by using Plugin manager `vim-plug`. There I noticed some fonts missing (rectangle box), for which I installed `JetBrains Mono` Nerd font which gave me
[image: After installing JetBrains Mono]
in the `air-line` status bar in `neovim`, which isn't also since it can be seen that some icons are overlapping each other.

I then tried installing `vim-devicons` to get some fancy icons, but that gave me this
[image: After installing vs-devicons]

The strange glyphs can be seen. While looking at the `:help airline-customizations`, I noted some of the symbols there for `old-vim-poweline` fonts are also the same rendered glyphs.

[image: airline-customization]

It looks to me like glyphs that could not be rendered properly, unlike the not-installed characters.

For this, I checked the readme(s) for the `vim-devicons`, and several others, which seemed to be saying that I need a patched [`Nerd Font`](https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts). I downloaded already before `JetBrains mono`, I also tried some other font e.g. `Fira Code`, but no success!

I tried adding the line `let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1` in `.vimrc` file as well as tried adding those `airline-customization` suggested lines, but it didn't work.

My system is

```
5.19.0-45-generic #46~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Jun 7 15:06:04 UTC 20 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, finally got which fonts were missing. It was not getting installed somehow with the Nerd fonts I tried installing.

It was solved by installing
[`Symbols Nerd Font`](https://www.nerdfonts.com/font-downloads) which has only symbols(glyphs).